# Urban Airship In-App messages shown in wrong position

Tags: android, ios, mobile, notifications, urbanairship.com

I’m trying to use the Urban Airship library to send In-App messages to the user on my Android app.

The problem is that I want the message to be shown in the top position, so I set this up in the UA panel (as shown in the screenshot below)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1kW.png)

but the messages continue to display on the bottom of the screen.

I’m adding the library in the gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:6.1.2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have logs that display the received in-app message push bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to configure it also on Urban Airship dashboard. 
Go on Settings -> Configuration -> In-app Message. And here you can choose the position you want for in-app (top or bottom).

Hope it helps.